# Win 32 API c++ Notepad Menu isn't work

Tags: winapi, notepad

I'm coding a application like Notepad in Win32 c++. But when i change szClassName in createWindow(), the menu can't work although it still show it when I run

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable


   hMenu = LoadMenu(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_NOTEPAD));

   hWnd = CreateWindow(L"EDIT", szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, hMenu, hInstance, NULL);

  //SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)WndProc);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);



   return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: You want your main window to be an edit control or what? That won't work.

Comment: Yes. I'm beginning to learn Win32 api and I don't know how to make a application like Notepad

Comment: [Walkthrough: Creating Windows Desktop Applications (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In `CreateWindow()`, the `hMenu` parameter is the control ID but not the menu handle.

I suggest creating the main window before adding a textbox:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc;
// ...
wc.lpszClassName="window class";
wc.lpszMenuName=hMenu;
// ...
RegisterWindowEx(&wc);
hWnd=CreateWindow("window class", ...);

// When processing WM_CREATE message in WndProc()
hEdit=CreateWindow("EDIT","your textbox", ... /* set hWndParent as hWnd */);
```

I think [theForger's Win32 API Programming Tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/start.html) is also a good place for you to start.